# Copying a field (column) value from a Voronoi polygon into the point inside that polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, voronoi-thiessen

I'm relatively new in GIS and I am using QGIS. I'm trying to find a way to copy a field value from a voronoi polygon layer into each point that is currently inside the said polygon. [image]

Each voronoi polygon contains a unique population field value. Also, each polygon contains exactly 10 points distributed randomly within. What I intend to do is to **copy the population values from each polygon into the points within the same polygon** then divide them by 10 - essentially distributing the population to every point.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Join Attributes by Location` tool to copy `Population` values into points, then `Field Calculator` to divide them by 10.

1. Set `Base Layer` to point layer,
2. `Join Layer` to Voronoi layer,
3. Check `within`,
4. Select `Population` field,
5. Select `... (one to many)` and run the tool.

[image]

You will get a new point layer having `Population` field.

7. Open Attribute Table (using `Right Click -> Open Attribute Table` or just F6).
8. Click "Field Calculator" button ([image])
9. Specify a field name
10. Select "integer" as field type
11. Then use `Population/10` and click OK.

[image]